# Subscribe to dynamically added content in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm using knockout.js 2.3.0 and I'm working with a table that has dynamically generated content. Each of the table rows has a checkbox on it, and I'm trying to trigger an event each time one of the checkboxes is checked/unchecked.

Here's the html table

```
<table>
    <tbody  data-bind ="foreach: additionalOptions">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="optionCheckbox" 
                       data-bind="checked: selectedOption"/>
            </td>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: price" ></td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is how the content is actually added to the additionalOptions array

```
function addOptions(id,name,price){
    var self = this;
    self.id = id;
    self.name = name;
    self.price = price;
    self.selectedOption = ko.observable(false);
}


self.additionalOptions = ko.observableArray();
self.additionalOptions.push(new addOptions(data[i].id, 
                                           data[i].name, 
                                           data[i].price));
```

When I subscribe to `additionalOptions` it only triggers when the table is filled with content. I even tried to manually `subscribe` using jQuery, but that didn't work either. Here are the two things I tried.

```
self.additionalOptions.subscribe(function(){
    alert('Box has been checked!')
});

$(".optionCheckbox").change(function(){
    alert('Box has been checked');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is subscribe to the `selectedOption`.

You can do it in `addOptions`:

```
self.selectedOption = ko.observable(false);
self.selectedOption.subscribe(function () { alert("Checbox change"); });
```

Or after you push it into the observableArray:

```
self.additionalOptions.push(new addOptions(data[i].id, 
                                           data[i].name, 
                                           data[i].price)); 
self.additionalOptions()[self.additionalOptions().length -1].selectedOption.subscribe(function () { alert("Checbox change"); });
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly and was very easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, you're dynamically creating content but the click handlers aren't working correctly. My guess is that when you call the binder the content you're targeting may not exist yet.

I would try delegating off of the main table instead (or whatever containing element works best).

JS

```
$('table').on('click', '.optionCheckbox', function(){
   alert('box has been checked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can see is to subscribe to the selection when you create the additionOptions object.  Like so:

```
function checkboxTriggered(value) {
    alert(value ? "Checked!" : "Unchecked!")   
}

function addOptions(id,name,price){
    var self = this;
    self.id = id;
    self.name = name;
    self.price = price;
    self.selectedOption = ko.observable(false);
    self.selectedOption.subscribe(checkboxTriggered);
}
```

Or, if you define the function within the `addOptions` function, you can use closure to reference properties specific to the row that's been selected.  Example:

```
function addOptions(id,name,price){
    var self = this;
    self.id = id;
    self.name = name;
    self.price = price;
    self.selectedOption = ko.observable(false);
    self.selectedOption.subscribe(function () {
        alert("Triggered row with id: "+self.id);
    });
}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Retsam19/r7r69/1/